# Check if the user is present in AD group inside Sharepoint Group Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, user

We have a SharePoint group and inside that group have an active directory group. IS it possible using JSOM to find out if the user belongs to the AD group which is added inside the Sharepoint group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That data isn't stored in SharePoint, it's stored in Active Directory. So you'll need to run some server-side code against your AD to get that.